# compare current and next value in datatable

Tags: c#, if-statement

i have tried to write code to compare the values in 'mainMenuNum' column of datatable. if values are not equal only then it should get printed to console.

```
for (int index = 0; index <= numRows; index++)
{
    if (index == 0 || index <= numRows)
    {
        if (dt.Rows[index]["mainMenuNum"].ToString() != 
            dt.Rows[index  - 1]["mainMenuNum"].ToString())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[index]["mainMenuNum"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When `index = 0` `dt.Rows[index  - 1]` will be `dt.Rows[-1]`!! Also your first `if` statement seems meaningless.

Comment: okay so what statement should i write to get the unique values printed

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int index = 0; index < numRows; index++)
{
      if (index < numRows-1)
      {
         if (dt.Rows[index]["mainMenuNum"].ToString() != dt.Rows[index+1]["mainMenuNum"].ToString())
          {
             Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[index]["mainMenuNum"].ToString());
          }
      }        
}
```

Comment: it gives exception at [index+1]: 'There is no row at position 5.'

Comment: how is numRows defined?

Comment: numRows = dt.Rows.Count; //returns '5' value because my datatable has five rows

Comment: it doesnot print last value. value is different though